How to Disable AP Isolation on Linksys WRT 1900 AC v2 with Stock Firmware for LAN and Wi-Fi Device Connectivity?
I am having trouble disabling AP isolation on my Linksys WRT 1900 AC v2 router with stock firmware. I have two devices that both have internet access - one is connected to the LAN and the other is connected via Wi-Fi. Despite both devices being connected to the same router, they can’t ping and connect to each other.
Can you help me find the configuration to disable AP isolation? Both devices have internet access coming from the same router.

The last sentence in the first paragraph appears to be incomplete? // AP Isolation only affects Wi-Fi to Wi-Fi communication.

Hi @DanielB thanks for pointing out I edited the post to better describe the problem.

It seems your WiFi device is connecting to the guest network instead of the main one. Your router doesn't have any specific "AP isolation" setting, it does that automatically via the guest AP.
